# Possible number of permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I've generally been seeing the formula nPr = n!/(n-r)! to calculate the number of permutations.

But this is the case only when elements cannot be repeated, am I correct?

If elements can be repeated, then it would just be n^r right?

If someone could tell me if I'm understanding this properly, that would be great.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Yes,you are right

Comment: We can think of it as counting the $r$-letter "words" over  an $n$-letter alphabet. The first letter can be chosen in $n$ ways. For each such choice, there are $n$ ways to choose the second letter. So the number of ways to choose the first two letters is $n^2$. For every such choice, there are $n$ ways to choose the third letter, so there are $n^2\cdot n=n^3$ ways to choose the first three letters. And so on.

Comment: that helps a lot!